# Cannot pass instance of UIVewController - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have an app with a method I have made, the idea is that this method will open whatever view controller I want. I made it so I would have to have lots of copies of the same code. However, it won't work, Xcode keeps on coming up with the error:

> Invalid operands to binary expression (UIViewController *) and 'unsigned long(*)(const char*)')

Here is my method:

```
-(void)open_view_controller:(UIViewController *)controller_name :(NSString *)view_name {

    controller_name *screen = [[controller_name alloc] initWithNibName:view_name bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am simply trying to avoid doing this:

```
CallCreator *screen = [[CallCreator alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallCreator" bundle:nil];
screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
```

What can I do to fix this error? I don't get what is wrong, I am passing in the correct type - `UIViewController`.

Thanks for your time, Dan.

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya No not in this case. I am using XIBs.

Comment: You must do properly naming each method in iOS.

Comment: Please check latest answer. I think this time we are near to correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `Class` instead of `UIViewController *`

```
- (void)presentViewControllerOfClass:(Class)controllerClass viewName:(NSString *)viewName;
{
    UIViewController *screen = [[controllerClass alloc] initWithNibName:viewName bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

which would be used like

```
[self presentViewControllerOfClass:MyViewController.class viewName:@"MyViewController"];
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way your Viewcontroller name in nib file and view_name parmeter string must be same.

```
+ (void)open_view_controller:(UIViewController *)controller_name :(NSString *)view_name {
    Class class = NSClassFromString(view_name);
    controller_name = [[class alloc] initWithNibName:view_name bundle:nil];
    controller_name.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:controller_name animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Second way,

```
+ (void)open_view_controller:(Class)controller_name :(NSString *)view_name {

    UIViewController *controller = [[controller_name alloc] initWithNibName:view_name bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: But thats just the name of the method... I don't think that is causing the issue. The bit where you put "viewName", is not necessary. The method should still work without it, its just there for developer reference.

Comment: @Supertecnoboff yeah, you are right. Thanks for amending this

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply use a variable of a particular type to instantiate another object of that type. `alloc` is a class method on `Class`. You can use `NSClassFromString` to obtain the `Class` object based on a string value and then use that to instantiate your object

I think you wanted to do this -

```
-(void)open_view_controller:(NSString *)controller_name :(NSString *)view_name {

    UIViewController *screen = [[NSClassFromString(controller_name) alloc] initWithNibName:view_name bundle:nil];
    screen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:screen animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To use this you can then say

```
[someObject open_view_controller:@"CallCreator" :@"CallCreator"]
```

I would suggest that you change the method signature to comply with Objective C conventions -

```
-(void) openViewControllerWithClassName:(NSString *)className nibName:(NSString *)nibName
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you have mentioned, controller_name is expected to be an object of type UIViewController. You cannot instantiate an object again.
To be more clear, when you write: 
`-(void)open_view_controller:(UIViewController *)controller_name :(NSString *)view_name`
Here, `(UIViewController *)controller_name` means that you are passing an object controller_name of class type UIViewController.

What you should be doing here instead is, passing an NSString for view controller's class name and then trying to instantiate using something like this:

```
-(void)openViewController:(NSString *)controllerName viewName:(NSString *)viewName {
    id obj = [[NSClassFromString(controllerName) alloc] init];
    //rest of the code
}
```